# Why is uses-permission removed from manifest when exporting APK?

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions

When signing the app, ready for uploading to the Play Store, the following permission is automatically removed from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: what do you mean by auto remove?

Comment: it mean when i exported, the eclipse will remove this code in manifest.xml

Comment: This is very clear.  I have the same problem.  When signing the app for uploading to the play store, any permission set in the manifest file are removed.

Comment: Does this happen with every project or just some projects?

Comment: For me I only have two projects and it happens on both.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this problem the simple answer is:

Do not attempt to edit AndroidManifest.xml file found in the bin directory. You need to change the file in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The android project that you are building in eclipse will show two Android Manifest files.

1. A Manifest file In the bin folder
2. The second manifest file is stored outside, usually found below the libs and res folder in the package manager directory.You will find it if you look for it carefully.

You need to edit the Manifest File mentioned in (2) to make permanent changes to the Manifest.

Changes made in the Manifest stored in the bin will be removed.